# the_content() not outputting anything (Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, the-content

Hi i'm using the custom post types UI and advanced custom fields plugin and would like to use the default content editor as one of my fields for a custom post type. 
When i use the_content(); in the template code to output the content it doesn't work.

```
  <div class="singleProjectContainer">
      <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
      <p><?php the_field('description'); ?></p>             
      <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
```

Can someone please help me with this. I've searched google but i'm seeing answers related more to content filters.

[image: Advanced Custom Fields Options]

Answer (score 1):

Be more specific while asking. Asuming you're using WYSIWYG editor in a custom field.

To retrieve custom field value, **the_content()** won't work. You must use something like this

```
echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'meta_filed_key',  TRUE);
```

Comment: It is WYSIWYG, not WYGIWYS. Please update your answer.

Comment: @Umi, you should direct your comment at Enthusiast, not me, I just corrected him.

Comment: @Enthusiast Sorry i thought i was quite specific since the content field for Wordpress is a WYSIWYG editor. Advanced Custom Fields gives an option to hide/show the Content Editor when creating custom fields and i chose to show it. I just want to know how to ouput what i wrote in the content WYSIWYG editor

Comment: Are you telling about "Field Type" drop down which let you choose WYSIWYG/Text area etc? If yes, you'll see a field called "Field Name". Let, the value of field name is "hello_test"

So you need **echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'hello_test',  TRUE);** where **$post_id** is the ID of the post/custom type. You can get ID within loop using $post->ID or outside loop **global $post; $post_id = $post->ID;**

Am I clear?

Comment: @Enthusiast Thanks for the reply, no it is not the "Field Type" drop down. There is a section called "Options" below the area where you fill in a new field, i edited my question by uploading an image showing the Options section so you can have a better idea. I unchecked the 'Content Editor' check box so i can have the regular Wordpress WYSIWYG content field in my custom Post.So i just want to output what is in that Content field,However using the_content() doesn't output anything - that is the problem.Hope my question is clearer now?

Comment: I was totally outside. This seems you're in custom type, not field. the_content() should work inside loop. For outside, use **echo get_the_content($post_id);**

Comment: @Enthusiast Um this 'options' section in the picture above is from Custom Fields, below the area for setting 'Rules'. 
I tried the code
       <?php $post_id = $post->ID; 
       echo get_the_content($post_id); ?>
still doesn't output anything.
I'm inside the loop of my custom post type and don't understand why the_content(): is not working 
 I'm just confused :(

Comment: As far I know WordPress, the image represents a custom type's option and all of the options are WordPress's feature, not custom field. Please share the template code so that anyone from this community can help you.